# Binding Multiple MvxSpinner to a ICommand

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am creating varied number of MvxSpinners programmatically. The number of the MvxSpinners generated cannot be predetermined. It is determined by the user input.

I have a  `List<Beneficiary>`. Each MvxSpinner is meant to update each `Beneficiary` in the collection.

Since I cannot determine the number of MvxSpinner (which corresponds to the count of the `Beneficiary` in the collection) to be generated, I am forced to have one `ICommand` to handle all the `HandleSelectedItem event` of the MvxSpinners.

**The Challenge**

I am having difficulty determining the index of the `List<Beneficiary>` to update depending on the MvxSpinner the user clicked.

**An Example**

let

```
var BeneficiaryList=new List<Beneficiary>()
```

If there are 5 `Beneficiary` object in the collection, 5 MvxSpinner will be generated.

If the user selects a MVXSpinner which is meant to update index 2 of the collection, how do i determine the index of `Beneficary` to update?

**What I have tried**

```
 private IList<Beneficiary> _beneficiaryList;
    public IList<Beneficiary> BeneficiaryList
    {
        get { return _beneficiaryList; }
        set { _beneficiaryList= value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => BeneficiaryList); }
    }

 public ICommand UpdateBeneficiary=> new MvxCommand<Beneficiary>(item =>
    {
        //item is of type Beneficiary
        //But I do not know which index of BeneficiaryList to update
    });
```

Your help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use an ObservableCollection instead of the List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is interesting to answer my own question.

What I did was to give each Spinner a unique ID that corresponds to the index of the collection.

I created a custom Spinner called `MvxSpinnerIndexer` extending `MvxSpinner` (I really do not think it matters. You can just extend `Spinner`). `MvxSpinnerIndexer` retrieved the Id and the `SelectedItem` and then placed the two into a `Dictionary`

Here is the source for `MvxSpinnerIndexer`

```
        public class MvxSpinnerIndexer : Spinner
        {
           public MvxSpinnerIndexer(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
            : this(
                context, attrs,
                new MvxAdapter(context)
                {
                    SimpleViewLayoutId = global::Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line
                })
               { }

        public MvxSpinnerIndexer(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, IMvxAdapter adapter)
            : base(context, attrs)
        {
            var itemTemplateId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadListItemTemplateId(context, attrs);
            var dropDownItemTemplateId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadDropDownListItemTemplateId(context, attrs);
            adapter.ItemTemplateId = itemTemplateId;
            adapter.DropDownItemTemplateId = dropDownItemTemplateId;
            Adapter = adapter;
            SetupHandleItemSelected();
        }

        public new IMvxAdapter Adapter
        {
            get { return base.Adapter as IMvxAdapter; }
            set
            {
                var existing = Adapter;
                if (existing == value)
                    return;

                if (existing != null && value != null)
                {
                    value.ItemsSource = existing.ItemsSource;
                    value.ItemTemplateId = existing.ItemTemplateId;
                }

                base.Adapter = value;
            }
        }

        [MvxSetToNullAfterBinding]
        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return Adapter.ItemsSource; }
            set { Adapter.ItemsSource = value; }
        }

        public int ItemTemplateId
        {
            get { return Adapter.ItemTemplateId; }
            set { Adapter.ItemTemplateId = value; }
        }

        public int DropDownItemTemplateId
        {
            get { return Adapter.DropDownItemTemplateId; }
            set { Adapter.DropDownItemTemplateId = value; }
        }

        public ICommand HandleItemSelected { get; set; }
        public int ViewId { get; set; }

        private void SetupHandleItemSelected()
        {
            ItemSelected += (sender, args) =>
            {
                //sender.
                var control = (MvxSpinnerIndexer)sender;
                var controlId = control.Id;
                var position = args.Position;
                HandleSelected(position, controlId);
            };
        }

        protected virtual void HandleSelected(int position, int? controlId)
        {
            var item = Adapter.GetRawItem(position);
            var content = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Index", controlId}, {"SelectedItem", item}};

            //var param = new ListItemWithIndexModel { Index = controlId, SelectedItem = item };
            if (HandleItemSelected == null
                || item == null
                || !HandleItemSelected.CanExecute(content))
                return;

            HandleItemSelected.Execute(content);
        }
    }
```

**In your ViewModel**

```
public ICommand SpinnerSelected => new MvxCommand<Dictionary<string, object>>(item =>
    {
        var selectedItem = item["SelectedItem"] as ListItemModel;//Cast to the actual model
        var index = item["Index"] as int?;//The index of the collection to update

    });
```

I believe this will be useful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a List of ICommands too, one for each spinner. Something like this in your view model...

```
private IList<ICommand> _commands;
public IList<ICommand> Commands {
    get {
        if (_commands == null) {
            _commands = BeneficiaryList.Select(x => new MvxCommand<Beneficiary>(item => {
                ...
            }));
        }
        return _commands;
    }
}
```

And set up your bindings like this (assuming you've got a list of spinners)

```
for (int i = 0; i < spinners.Count; i++) {
    var spinner = spinners[i];
    set.Bind (spinner).To(vm => vm.Commands[i]);
}
```